# How to create different top tabs in multiple screens in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-tabnavigator

I am looking to create different tabs in different screens. This is a little hard to explain so i will post a couple photos to illustrate my desire output.

I've already created a tab navigator using createMaterialTopTabNavigator, but it seems like i can't apply the same logic twice in a whole separate js file.  My javascript is fairly weak.

This is my code for the first tab navigation(newsfeed + services). I am looking to do the exact same thing except with different tab titles.

My question is, how would i go about achieving my desire output?

```
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import NewsfeedActivity from './NewsfeedActivity';
import ServiceActivity from './ServiceActivity';



export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Newsfeed:{screen: NewsfeedActivity},
    Services:{screen:ServiceActivity}
},
{
    initialRouteName:'Services',
    swipeEnabled:true,
    navigationOptions:({navigation})=>({
         header:null

    }),
    tabBarOptions:{
        activeTintColor:'#65FAE9',
        inactiveTintColor:'white',
        allowFontScaling:true,
        indicatorStyle:{borderBottomColor:'#65FAE9', borderBottomWidth:4,},
        style:{backgroundColor:'#515276',paddingBottom:5},
        labelStyle:{fontWeight:'bold',marginTop:'40%'},  
    },     
 },

);
```

**What i have:**

[image]

**What Im looking to create:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can nest multiple navigators.

If your desired output is to have the bottom navigation different in "Newsfeed" and different in "Services" , then instead of passing a page as the screen , you can pass a bottomNavigator

```
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator,createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import NewsfeedActivity from './NewsfeedActivity';
import ServiceActivity from './ServiceActivity';



export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Newsfeed:{screen: firstBottomNavigation},
    Services:{screen: secondBottomNavigation }
},
{
    initialRouteName:'Services',
    swipeEnabled:true,
    navigationOptions:({navigation})=>({
         header:null

    }),
    tabBarOptions:{
        activeTintColor:'#65FAE9',
        inactiveTintColor:'white',
        allowFontScaling:true,
        indicatorStyle:{borderBottomColor:'#65FAE9', borderBottomWidth:4,},
        style:{backgroundColor:'#515276',paddingBottom:5},
        labelStyle:{fontWeight:'bold',marginTop:'40%'},  
        },     
     },

    ); 

const firstBottomNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
FirstTab:{screen FirstTab},
SecondTab: {screen:SecondTab}
})

const secondBottomNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
ThirdTab:{screen ThirdTab},
SecondTab: {screen:SecondTab} //You can recycle screens
})
```

You can get creative , you can try nesting a toptabnavigator in a bottomnavigator ,etc . But don't make things too complicated because if it's complicated for you, imagine how hard is gonna be for the user